# How to generate different name for textbox input which is created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dynamically created textboxes with delete buttons for 7 days of the week using jQuery append. I'm using the same function for the 7 append buttons, its working fine, but I need to generate text boxes with different name.

I means if I click on Sunday add button textbox name or id should be `sunday text1` `sunday text2`, and same for other weekdays, how can I do it?

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap");
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button");
    var i = 1; 
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        i++;
            $(this).parent().append('<div><label class="titlesmall-font">From time</label><input type="text" class="form-control"/><label class="titlesmall-font"> To Time</label><input type="text" class="form-control" /><label class="titlesmall-font">Price</label><input type="text" class="form-control" /><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove_field padding-top-5 delete"  style="margin-top:5px; margin-left:4%;" value="Delete"></div><div class="clearfix"></div>'); 
    });
    
    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); i--;
    })
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Observe following changes,

```
var $wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap");
var $add_button      = $(".add_field_button");

$add_button.click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    i++;
    $(this).parent().append('<div><label class="titlesmall-font">From time</label><input type="text" class="form-control"/><label class="titlesmall-font"> To Time</label><input type="text" class="form-control" /><label class="titlesmall-font">Price</label><input type="text" class="form-control" /><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove_field padding-top-5 delete"  style="margin-top:5px; margin-left:4%;" value="Delete"></div><div class="clearfix"></div>'); 
});

$wrapper.on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); i--;
});
```

As,

`$wrapper` and `$add_button` already are jQuery Object so no need to wrap then again inside `$`